# バケツソートの最低ケースを改善するためには

Tags: c, アルゴリズム, データ構造

バケツソート(Bucket Sort)の平均計算量はO(n)ですが、もしデータが均一に分布してない場合、最悪計算量はO(n^2)になってしまいます。しかし、その場合他のアルゴリズムと組み合わせることによって計算量は改善できるのでしょうか？

教科書からの問題なのですが、二分探索を使用できるというヒントを与えられました。しかし、二分探索を使用する意味がよくわかりません。Merge Sortを組み合わせたならO(nlogn)まで削減できますが、その他の方法が思いつきません。なにかアイデアを共有していただけると嬉しいです。

バケツソート
ref: Algorithm Introduction, MIT Press

擬似コードへの入力は要素数 n の配列 A であり，各要素 A[i] は 0≤ A[i] < 1 を満たすと仮 定する．連結リストを要素とする補助配列 B0..n−1 を擬似コードは使用するが， リストを維持する機構は（擬似コードの外に）存在すると仮定する

```
BUCKET-SORT(A) 
1 n = A.length 
2 B[0..n−1] を新しい配列とする 
3 for i =0to n−1 
4     B[i] を空リストに初期化する 
5 for i =1to n 
6     A[i] をリスト B[nA[i]] に挿入する 
7 for i =0to n−1 
8     リスト B[i] を挿入ソートでソートする 
9 リスト B[0],B[1],...,B[n−1] をこの順序で連接する
```

Comment: ここでいう n は、ソートしたい配列 A の長さですか？　それとも、用意しなければいけないバケツの個数ですか？　疑似コードでは `n = A.length` と初期化しつつ、バケツ `B` の個数としても使われているように読めます。計算量を書く際は変数が何を指しているのかやどのような仮定がなされているのかを明らかにしていただけると助かります。

Comment: 疑似コードにおいて for がどこまで影響を与えているのか明らかではないので、上手く書き直していただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 申し訳ありません。修正しました。

Comment: おそらくご質問の本質とは関係が薄いですが、これは実数ないし浮動小数点数を対象としたソートでしょうか……？ 自然数か整数か実数かでは考えることや計算量が変わってくる場合があるのでそのあたりも記述があると嬉しいです（先のコメントの際はてっきり自然数かと勘違いしていました）。`B[nA[i]] に挿入する` という部分では `int(n * A[i])` 的なことをされているのでしょうか。

Comment: 掲載された疑似コード、一般的なバケツソートに対して、「バケツの数k = 入力配列の要素数n」「Aの各要素の範囲は[0.0, 1.0)」(その上で疑似コード6の`nA[i]`は`floor(n * A[i])`と解釈)と言う制約が加えられているようです。「教科書から」と言うことですが、教科書にはそのような制約事項は書かれていなかったでしょうか? もし書いていたのなら、そういったことは全部ご質問に転記してください。また、他に何らかの制約事項はないのでしょうか? 今のところの記述だと、どこでどんなふうに「二分探索を使用できる」のか全く分かりません…。

Comment: 原文では "Explain why the worst-case running time for bucket sort is Θ(n^2). What simple change to the algorithm preserves its linear average-case running time and makes its worst-case running time Θ(n*log(n))?" となっていて、worst case というのは単一の bucket に全ての値が集中してしまう場合かと思われます。Insertion sort ではなく heap sort か merge sort を使用すれば Θ(n\*log(n)) に収まるのでしょうね。